# DNS server can't resolve localhost name

Tags: linux, dns, localhost, rhel, domain-name

I am trying to set up an apache server on my RHEL6.4 vm and can't because dnsmasq can't recognize the hostname for some reason:

```
nslookup rhel64.example.com
Server:         xxx.xxx.xx.1
Address:        xxx.xxx.xx.1#53

** server can't find rhel64.exmple.com: NXDOMAIN
```

/etc/hosts

```
xxx.x.x.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search novalocal example.com
nameserver xxx.xxx.xx.1
```

Please let me know if there is anything you need to see to solve my problem. I cannot use a different dns server.

Looking for a way to make dnsmasq resolve the hostname without changing dns servers.

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS client was never initiated when the virtual machine booted up

Answer (score 0):

Can you output your /etc/sysconfig/iptables, /etc/sysconfig/network and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0?